# if Opportunity profile owner name is Shiva Nand then new opportunity is created

Tags: apex, visualforce

Please see my below code

```
trigger exampleInvalidTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {  
    for (Opportunity oOpportunity : trigger.new) {
        if (oOpportunity.Owner. == 'Shiva Nand') {
            oOpportunity.IsExecutiveOpportunity = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Trigger.new` does not have context into lookup fields or children objects.

You will need to query for the `opportunity.owner.name` in a bulkified manner.

Comment: if (oOpportunity.Owner.name == 'Shiva Nand') {
            oOpportunity.IsExecutiveOpportunity = true;
        }

Comment: still some changes is required on above code

Comment: @user28787 - take a look at [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/123462/2602)

Comment: ok i got it it's my mistake sir